# Dates switching from dd mm to mm dd in VBA filter

Tags: excel, vba, date

I'm trying to filter by date in Excel using VBA.

The dates transpose when entering the filter, with month and day being swapped to U.S instead of European dates.

The dates in the table are formatted as short dates and the dates entered into the text boxes are in the correct format.

dateselect is the check box to activate the filter and datestart and datefinish are the text boxes holding the dates.

```
If dateselect = True Then

    With Worksheets("Data").Range("C:C")
      .AutoFilter field:=1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria1:=">=" & Datestart, Criteria2:="<=" & datefinish
    End With

End If
```

I tried adding format to the dates but I get an overflow error.

```
If dateselect = True Then

    With Worksheets("Data").Range("C:C")
      .AutoFilter field:=1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria1:=">=" & Format(Datestart, dd/mm/yyyy), Criteria2:="<=" & Format(datefinish, dd/mm/yyyy)
    End With

End If
```

So with one I get transposed dates and if I try to force the format I get an overflow.

Comment: Is this code in the `Worksheet_Change` event?

Comment: Try using `DateValue`

Comment: The code is activated when you press a button and is in the macro for that button.  There is more data around it but that's not relevant to this question. Just tried DateValue and it still transposed.

Comment: Are the dates "real Excel dates" and not text representations of dates? (cell format is irrelevant to answer this question)  What are your windows regional settings for dates?

Comment: Just tried the CDbl method and it's now filtering the wrong column. Instead of the date column (C) it's filtering the engine rig column (A). My regional settings are for the UK, if I put the function TODAY into a cell I get dd/mm/yyyy. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "real Excel dates" rather than text representations?

Comment: It works like you do it. You have dates like the output of =TODAY() in your cells (and that is a good explanation). Those dates are shown as a text depending on number format, but internally stored as number with decimals. With them, the `CDbl` comparison works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use date values in your cells, like the result of =TODAY(), you can use `Range.Autofilter` with `CDbl` comparisons.

By `CDate` you can ensure, that your variables "datestart" and "datefinish" are also date values.

`CDbl` works almost perfect, as a date value internally consists of an integer part (days since 1900) and its decimals (part of a day, i. e. hours, minutes, seconds).

```
With Worksheets("Data").Range("C:C")
    .AutoFilter field:=1, _
    Operator:=xlAnd, _
    Criteria1:=">=" & CDbl(CDate(datestart)), _
    Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(CDate(datefinish))
End With
```

Be aware that criteria <, <=, >, >=, <> will work like above, but if dates must be filtered equal to a *single* given date, a simple "=..." either needs the exact string notation of the dates in your worksheet (depending of the number format of the cells) or following, independent of date format:

```
With Worksheets("Data").Range("C:C")
    .AutoFilter field:=1, _
    Criteria1:="<=" & CDbl(myDate), Operator:=xlAnd, _
    Criteria2:=">=" & CDbl(myDate)
```

Comment: Just tried this and it's now filtering the wrong column, A instead of C. I'm really confused now. However the numbers it's adding to the filter give the right dates when put in date format.

Comment: OK, changed the field to 3 and it's now filtering correctly. Thanks for the help.